# Loading configuration before Jasmine Test

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I am working on a larger project on Angular 4. We get JSON Data from the Server and then display that data in a special table component on the client.

The specialty of the table is that you can define client side which columns are displayed. To find out which columns there are we get a configuration JSON File from the server. And because we only need this thing once and before the module is loaded I placed the loading mechanism in a guard. So far this works fine.

I have 2 requests:

- Get column declaration in the guard
- Get data from the server and fill the table. That's done in the component

Now I also have to test this. And that's where my trouble begins. I can't get the column JSON request done before jasmine executes the unit tests.

```
fdescribe('Component: MyComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let component: MyComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        FieldConfigurationService
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'resources/i18n', '.json'),
          deps: [Http]
        })
      ]
    }).overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: []
      }
    }).compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
      });
  }));

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('when field Configuration is loaded', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
      console.log(1);
      component.fieldConfigurationService.loadConfiguration(true);
      console.log(2);
    }));

    describe('when the component is ready for use', () => {
      console.log(3);
    });
  });
});
```

The output of the console.log is 3,1,2.

How would I have to place the component.fieldConfigurationService.loadConfiguration(); command so that the thing is executed before the block with console.log(3) is started.

I have also tried to insert this in the "then" section of the testbed. Whatever I have done so far the execution of the unit test always started before the data was loaded from the server due to the asynchronous nature of the data load process.

Any help on is higly appreciated.

The FieldConfigurationService looks like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class FieldConfigurationService {
  public config: any = {};
    public loadConfiguration(isUnitTest: boolean = false): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (isUnitTest) {
            if (!this.config) {
              this.config = this.readJSON('base/gulpdist/field-definition.json');
              resolve(this.config);
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          } else {
            if (!this.config) {
              this.getJSON().subscribe(
                data => {
                  this.config = data;
                  resolve(data);
                },
                error => reject(error)
              );
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          }
        });
    }
  }

    private readJSON(url) {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      let json = null;

      xhr.open('GET', url, false);

      xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
          console.error('readJSON', url, xhr.statusText);
        }
      };

      xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error('readJSON', url, xhr.statusText);
      };

      xhr.send(null);
      return json;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much
Simon

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a bad idea

```
public loadConfiguration(isUnitTest: boolean = false): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (isUnitTest) {
```

Unit testing shouldn't leak into your implementation details like this. What you *should* do is just mock the configuration data.

```
import { mockConfigData } from './whereever';

...
const config = new FieldConfigurationService();
config.config = mockConfigData;

providers: [
  { provide: FieldConfigurationService, useValue: config }
]
```

So you've set up the service to use some mock data from where ever the mock file might be. Now what you need to do is fix the `resolve(null)`

```
if (!this.config) {
  ...
} else {
  resolve(null);
}
```

What is the point of resolving `null`. The whole point of this logic is "if there is no config, fetch it, otherwise *return null???"*. Shouldn't it be "otherwise return the config"? So fix that. Make it resolve the config

```
if (!this.config) {
  ...
} else {
  resolve(this.config);
}
```

With this, the promise resolve synchronously, so you don't need to change anything with the test, unless you remove the `isUnitTest` crap, which I would highly suggest you do.

Comment: Hahahaha...Thank you. I was so focused on the Unit Test that I completely         ignored the FieldConfigurationService. It works now thanks to your input.